# Apps Script: Passing a callback to ServerHandler's callback

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a login form in google spreadsheet that allows me to login into an external application. My spreadsheet allows me to continuously communicate with this external application so that I can do task1, task2 and so on with it. I need to verify whether I'm logged in the external application before I can either do task1 or task2.

So my use case is :

1. User invokes task1
2. My code checks whether he is already logged in. If not, brings up login form.
3. The form then first checks login, then calls task1.
4. Later in future, user invokes task2.
5. My code needs to check the same scenario again to bring up login form.
6. Again my form checks user's login credentials and this time invokes task2.

Here's how my code looks :

```
function invokeTask1()
{
    //if user not logged in
        loginForm("performTask1");
    //else
        performTask1();//works fine.
}
```

My loginForm looks like this:

```
function loginForm(sCallbackFn)
{
    //Code to create UiInstance and populate it with username and password fields
    //for now, I tried hidden field storing callback for me.
    var hdnCallback = app.createHidden("executeAfterLogin", sCallbackFn).setName("proceedWithExecution");
    //then I already have ServerHandler for Ok Button Click
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('OkButtonEvent');
    handler.addCallbackElement(abcPanel);
    btnOk.addClickHandler(handler);
}
```

Then my OkButtonEvent is this one where I check for login and then perform corresponding task:

```
function OkButtonEvent(e)
{
    //code to pick out e.parameter values and check login on external server application
    //I don't know how to invoke e.parameter.proceedWithExecution here. 
    //This has failed to run without any errors though.
    eval(e.parameter.proceedWithExecution);
}
```

And lastly, I have these:

```
function performTask1()//and also performTask2()
{
    //doing something. But not getting invoked via login form's ServerHandler.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `this[e.parameter.proceedWithExecution]();`

This isn't a UiApp question per se though - that's just how you invoke a function by string name in JavaScript.